# Clickhouse subquery not allowed with CASE/IF statement

Tags: sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am trying to filter data with the help of a condition in click house. This is the query:

```
SELECT CASE

WHEN EXISTS (

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Time, Lon, Users FROM table1 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 5) WHERE Users>=75

)

THEN ( * FROM (SELECT Time, Lon, Users FROM table1 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 5) WHERE Users<75)

ELSE ( * WHERE 0=1)

END;
```

I had also tried simple IF condition in clickhouse but eve in that subquery didn't work. The query:

```
SELECT if((SELECT count() FROM table1 WHERE Users>=75)>0, SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Users<75, plus(2, 6));
```

Both time the basic error remains same:

```
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 77 ('default'): default.4g WHERE Users<75, plus(2, 6));
. Expected one of: LIKE, GLOBAL NOT IN, end of query, AS, DIV, IS, OR, QuestionMark, BETWEEN, NOT LIKE, MOD, AND, Comma, alias, IN, ILIKE, Dot, NOT ILIKE, NOT, token, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN (version 21.3.20.1 (official build))
```

Is there any way to run subqueries within CASE/IF in click house ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` directly in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Time, Lon, Users 
FROM table1 
WHERE Users < 75
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Users >= 75)
ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: The error from the question still persists. Anything inside EXISTS not working. I even tried lines from the documentation - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/exists/

These are also not working.

Comment: @NILESHSUTHAR you can see in the documentation that the syntax I use is valid.

Comment: Yes. The syntax is valid according to the documentation. But even other syntaxes from Documentation are throwing errors. Can you try any syntax with subquery in your clickhouse?